# Method awaited and the program get out of the method before it ends

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am making this method to connect to thingsboard and getting a Token access, when the program starts it get out of the program before getting the token, I've already tried to lunch the program with just this method and nothing else after and it get the token, but if I put some code after calling this method, the program get out of the log method.

```
class Login
{
    public thingboardToken tbToken;
    public thingboardCredentials tbCredentials;
    public string thingsboardAPIUrl = "https://demo.thingsboard.io/api";

    public Login() {
        loginAsync();
    }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> loginAsync()
    {
        string requesturl = thingsboardAPIUrl + "/auth/login";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        tbCredentials = new thingboardCredentials();
        tbCredentials.username = "xxxxx";
        tbCredentials.password = "xxxxx";

        var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tbCredentials);
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(requesturl, byteContent);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        tbToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<thingboardToken>(responseString);

        return responseString;
    }
}
```

Expected getting a token.

Comment: yes posting and getting an acces token, and it works with this method, the problem is when i put code after Login(); like : Login l = new Login();   device d = new device (); my program start with login and goes directly to new device ();

Comment: I expect the compiler would have [warned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014) you about this - _"Because this call [Login] is not awaited, **execution of the current method continues before the call is completed**. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."_

Comment: in this method yes he warned me but i wasn't able to await the result of the call :/

Comment: Don't use constructors to execute functionality. Only for some variable initialization. Use an `public async Task Initialize() { }` instead. If the constructor raises an exception. you're also losing the instance of the newly created class.

Comment: I think you missed the point of what I was saying, you have posted your real password in this post meaning anyone can use your details.

Comment: @DavidG removed

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Yes, but it remains in the post history. OP should really change their password ASAP.

Comment: @DavidG yes I know, but I guess he doesn't get it

Comment: @DavidG the username and the password is just for a demo thingsboard online it doesnt have any impact on my work, thank's a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor, you are calling an `async` method without awaiting it. In your constructor, `loginAsync` task hasn't competed but the execution of the current method continues before the call is completed.

```
 public Login() {
        loginAsync();
 }
```

Don't put initialization code in your constructor, instead, do it like below:

```
public class Foo
{
   public Foo() {}
   public async Task LoginAsync() { ... }
}

var obj = new Foo();
await obj.LoginAsync();
```

In this approach, it wouldn't block the thread and it's better.

Comment: Ali brahimi thank you it is working with your solution

Comment: Suggesting to use `Task.Run` in the constructor is a terrible idea.

Comment: @DavidG Agree and already told him "Be careful, this solution synchronously blocks the thread."

Comment: It's not just about being careful, it shouldn't even have been a thought in the first place.

Comment: @DavidG completely I changed it.

Comment: @AliBahrami when i use var obj = new Foo();
await obj.LoginAsync(); it said   Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>'

Comment: @zak92 could you update your question with updated code?

Comment: public class Login
{
   public Login() {}
   public async Task LoginAsync() { ... }
}

Login  l = new Login();
await l.LoginAsync();                                                                                                       when using it  raise an error "it works with your method before Task.Run()" @AliBahrami